# Insert object/file into Word form

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003, microsoft-word-2003, forms

I am setting up a form in MS Word. Users of the form will have to attach files that include results and other relevant data.

I'd like to use a protected form, but I can't find a way to allow users to insert these objects into the form. Is it even possible?

I've also thought about having them copy/paste paths to files on a shared drive, but sometimes the directories change or move so I'd really rather have embedded documents.

What alternatives are there, if what I want is not possible?

(using Office 2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a new section/section break where you want the inserted file to go, and unprotect that single section.

Comment: It's possible to un-protect parts of a form/document?

Comment: Indeed it is! Make sure you use section breaks befor and after the unprotected part, and it should give you a dropdown of selected sections in the "Protect Document" pane. Just leave the area you want them to insert in unprotected.

Comment: Article on section breaks: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/about-sections-and-section-breaks-HP005255035.aspx

Arcticle on unprotecting a section: http://www.infopackets.com/news/carols_corner_office/2007/20071213_unprotect_part_of_a_form_in_ms_word.htm

If you wanted a little more info. =)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following VBA script within a button click action, to simulate the "Insert Object" functionality within the document:

This code can go inside the button "click" event as-is.

```
' Browse & Select File
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the File that you want to insert"
        If .Show = True Then
            FiletoInsert = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

' Embed File Inline
    Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=FiletoInsert, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconLabel:=Right(FiletoInsert, Len(FiletoInsert) - InStrRev(FiletoInsert, "\"))
```